# Exporting Civil 3d Model to Google Earth (KML) shows strange triangular shadows

Tags: autocad

I am trying to export civil 3d model but when i do so the kml output shows shadows. Please refer attached image.
Is there any settings in Civil 3d to remove them.
Please help

[image]

Comment: Are they definitely shadows? Or could they be eg edges from a weird mesh creation? What does it look like in other software?

Comment: @Jonathan R Swift its just my guess that those are shadows. sorry i am new to civil 3d and i dont have access to other softwares. if you want i will share the file as well

Comment: Is that the output shown in Civil 3D, or in Google Earth?

Comment: @Jonathan its a google earth output (kml). sorry i cannot find way to attach my kml or dwg file with this post.

Comment: Right, but you're viewing that output in Civil 3D? What does it look like when you open it in Google Earth?

Comment: I have updated google earth output image in my main query. Thats how it looks in google earth. and i want to remove those black shadows.

Comment: Not shadows, but backwards triangles.  Google Earth wants triangles in a b c and Civil 3d is giving some as a c b.  Easy to check.  In Google Earth.  Go into model and see if any internal surfaces are blue.